# Google Cloud Run and golang goroutines

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm considering Google Cloud Run for some cron-like operations I need to perform. They will get triggered by an HTTP invocation. The invocation will return (likely with a 202) and continue running in the background via a golang goroutine.

But, I'm concerned that Google Cloud Run containers are destroyed when they're not handling HTTP requests. I could be part-way through my processing and get reaped.

Is there a way to tell GCR to keep the container alive until I'm finished?

Answer (score 7):

Cloud Run will scale your CPU down to nearly zero when it's not handling any requests, because you’re only paying when a request is being processed. (It's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#avoiding_background_activities)).

Therefore, **applications starting goroutines in the background are not suitable for Cloud Run**. If you do this, your goroutines will most likely starve for CPU time shares and your program may start behaving very weirdly (as it would be running on a very very slow CPU, if anything at all).

The miniscule amount of an inactive Cloud Run application gets is probably only good for garbage collection, which go runtime will be doing for you.

If you want to wait for your goroutine to finish during the context of the request, you should block the request from returning, by using something like a blocking-receive from a `chan`, or `sync.WaitGroup#Done()`.

Answer (score 1):

The fairly new Always On CPU feature of Cloud Run solves this.  Here is a link to the details: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation