# net/http: TLS handshake timeout when call external https from google cloud

Tags: go, ssl, timeout, google-cloud-run, handshake

I met the following error when I call the https link from the google cloud run . It works very well when the program calls the same link from my local computer.

I use golang "net/http" to call the https link. I don't know why it has problem when I deploy the program to the google cloud run.

Does anyone has the same issue as me? Any solution I can borrow?

Thanks in advance.

**"Post "https://integrations.thethingsnetwork.org/.....": net/http: TLS handshake timeout"**

Comment: Might be related to https://serverfault.com/questions/908141/docker-pull-tls-handshake-timeout. If the machine is too slow, the TLS timeout kicks in quite easily. Try extend the timeout for the connection.

Comment: Are you making this request while Cloud Run is **not** handling requests? If container isn't handling requests, CPU is scaled to ~0, and background tasks like such which will surface these timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running HTTP calls in a different go routine.
Fixed, after saw @AhmetB comment, by removing it.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257903/google-cloud-run-and-golang-goroutines).

Thanks @AhmetB :)